# Highmap: trigger hover + show tooltip of country on hover bubble data

Tags: highcharts

My highmap visualization has many series: country and bubbles. I want them use the same tooltip on hover one type of data item. The problem is highmap hasn't yet supported shared tooltip. Is there any idea/trick to get over this difficulty? Please suggest me some keyword so that I can continue searching/trying.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add this style and it's fine for me then:

```
.highcharts-mapbubble-series .highcharts-point {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi vuquanghoang, has your problem been fully resolved? If not, please provide me with some live example of the problem.